# Layout image source Is not changing in ImageView after using Layout Inflater

Tags: android, imageview, layout-inflater

I am trying to change the image in an ImageView of a different layout. For this, I am using Layout Inflator, because I don't know any other way.
The image gets visible when users click a button and according to the selected button, image gets visible. But this method is not working for me.

This is my layout file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentStart ="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical = "true"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the code which I am using:

```html
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.myImage2);
```

This is my service class:

```html
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("ON", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        n_hi = sharedPreferences.getInt("N_HI",0);
        n_wi = sharedPreferences.getInt("N_WI",0);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newLayout, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

        changeDesign();
    }

 
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("SizeChange"));
            if (isPortrait) {
                drawPortrait();
            } else {
                drawLandscape();
            }
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
 
 public void drawPortrait(){

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            if (d) {
                overlay = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;
            }else{
                overlay = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE;
            }
        } else {
            overlay = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        }
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            flag_p = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_DEFAULT |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
        } else {
            flag_p = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
        }
        floatingView = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.newLayout, null);
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                n_wi,
                n_hi,
                overlay,
                flag_p,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.addView(floatingView, params);
    }
```

My app is working on a service so I used this code in the service class and also on the main activity but it didn't work. Also, I tried to run it on start instead of using it on button press but still didn't work for me.

I am also not sure is this the right approach to do this any suggestion is also great. I am new in programming. Also, suggest that the source image I am changing still stays the same because the app might get closed but by using service app will still show the image, so what is the best option for that.

Comment: I don't uderstand your question... you have `Service` which is changing image in `Activity`? you should show more code, a lot more, whole mechanism... everything is fine with your currently posted code (besides that you are inflating new layout, but I don't see you are adding it do `Activity` /any `ViewGroup`)

Comment: Updated the question with more details. Please take a look again. Also, this service gets started when user press button in MainActivity.

Comment: And Thank you very very much for the help. I don't have words to thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question, but I can see some big flaws in posted code...

First of all this code do not belong to `Service`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.myImage2);
```

in second line you are inflating new `View v` without adding to parent (second param is `null`), so this `View` isn't shown to user anywhere... besides of that `Service` don't have own layout so you don't have any place to add this `View` for showing user

I think you are misunderstanding what `inflater` is... XML resources are like "sketches", inflater is **creating new `View`** basing on XML code, so every result is **new** object. If you change image on one `View` it won't automatically change in another... In other words, by code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
    ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) v1.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.myImage2);

    View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
    ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) v2.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

`iv2` will be still showing `R.drawable.my_image`, because it belongs to new, freshly created (inflated) `View v2`

I'm just suspecting that you are inflating this `View` inside `Activity` and think that when you inflate it in any other place in code and change its look (image) it will change in all inflated `View`s with this `id`... it won`t

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Now I Understand why it's not working. Thanks for the help.